# Linker error using RasGetEapUserIdentity in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, linker

Translated from Google Translate:

I try to use just `RasGetEapUserIdentity`, but unfortunately I fail at compile time.

## Output

`meinprogrammname.obj: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "_RasGetEapUserIdentityW@20" in function "_wmain".`

If the Properties ([ALT] + [F7]) under Linker -> Input -> additional dependencies `rasdial32.lib`, puts:

`LINK: fatal error LNK1104: File "rasdial32.lib" can not be opened.`

There is a new project as a Windows console application was created. Changes to settings I have made ​​none.

---

## Original Post:

ich versuche gerade `RasGetEapUserIdentity` zu benutzen, ich scheitere jedoch leider schon bei der Kompilierung.

## stdafx.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinNT.h>
#include <Ras.h>
```

## Ausgabe

`meinprogrammname.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_RasGetEapUserIdentityW@20" in Funktion "_wmain".`

Wenn unter Eigenschaften ([ALT]+ [F7]) unter Linker -> Eingabe -> Zusätzliche Abhängigkeiten `rasdial32.lib` hinzugefügt wird, erscheint:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: Datei "rasdial32.lib" kann nicht geöffnet werden.`

Es ist ein neues Projekt als Windows Konsolenanwendung angelegt worden. Änderungen an Einstellungen habe ich keine vorgenommen.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `rasdial32.lib` with `rasapi32.lib` in your Additional Dependencies.

Comment: @user1377060 Great :)  Feel free to accept the answer then (click on the white tick to the left).